# Alamofire 3.0 - EXC_BAD_ACCESS on iOS 9.1

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, ios9.1

Doubtful that this is a widespread issue, but hoping someone could help if they've had a similar problem.

I'm having this weird issue that only appears when running my App on the device, Alamofire works fine in the simulator.
This started to appear after I upgraded to iOS 9.1 on my device.

Now when I test the app on my device, as soon as I make my first Alamofire request, an EXC_BAD_ACCESS appears on the var components line under the defaultHTTPHeaders > acceptLanguage block (see Image)

[image]

The Code making the request is:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "/api/index.php", parameters: ["version": "1"]).responseJSON{
            response in
            
            if(response.result.isSuccess)
            {...
```

Using Breakpoints shows that the code does not progress to the ResponseJSON method.

Comment: I think changing the [] to [String]() would solved it

Comment: @horst - thanks for the help, but no dice :( - This is a problem within Alamofire 3.0 - which would surprise me because there is no open issue on Github about it.

Answer (score 2):

So I stumbled across this post in the Github:
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/881

Turns out that for whatever reason - you may need to delete your Derived Data folder if this starts happening.

To do so, navigate here:

`~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

Delete the folders that relate to your app causing this issue.
This should fix it!

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue and this did not work for me. How did you deploy your app the to the device? Just plug in, select the destination and select play?

Comment: Correct. Try deleting the App from your device, then running clean. Then run.

Comment: Ok, so I tried what you said. Removed the app from the device, removed DerivedData, Clean the app, reinstall. I still get this same error.

Comment: Hmm you might need to open up a new question then! Very odd! Good luck.

Comment: seems to be a configuration issue. I migrated all my files to a new project and then ran it and everything worked perfectly. It is weird, but doesn't seem to be an issue with the library like I initially thought.