# EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error In App, Alamofire 3.1.2

Tags: iphone, swift, alamofire

I'm running Xcode 7.1, with an iOS device on 9.1, and the latest version of Alamofire, I believe it's 3.1.2.

I've seen others with similar errors - [this one from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33403752/alamofire-3-0-exc-bad-access-on-ios-9-1) and [this one from their Github issues page](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/897) - to mine, but the resolutions did not work for me. The resolutions that worked in these scenarios seemed to be deleting the DerivedData folders, but that doesn't work in my situation.

The issue is that I can make web requests with Alamofire when I run in the simulator, but I get the following error (in the image) when I install the application on my device.

[image]

I've tried using a device running 9.1, 9.0.1 and 8.3. All of these devices crash when I attempt to make the web request. I'm stuck on this and I've made no headway. This worked until I updated all my pods in my podfile and my Xcode version a couple of nights ago.

I'm a newbie at iOS development, so if you need to see more error logs or things of that nature, let me know and I'll do my best to get you those. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Adding code for the `Alamofire.request` method as requested. Also adding code for the referenced `Manager.sharedInstance.request` method. These are methods within the Alamofire library itself.

```
// Alamofire.request
public func request(
    method: Method,
    _ URLString: URLStringConvertible,
    parameters: [String: AnyObject]? = nil,
    encoding: ParameterEncoding = .URL,
    headers: [String: String]? = nil)
    -> Request
{
    return Manager.sharedInstance.request(
        method,
        URLString,
        parameters: parameters,
        encoding: encoding,
        headers: headers
    )
}

// Manager.sharedInstance.request
public func request(
    method: Method,
    _ URLString: URLStringConvertible,
    parameters: [String: AnyObject]? = nil,
    encoding: ParameterEncoding = .URL,
    headers: [String: String]? = nil)
    -> Request
{
    let mutableURLRequest = URLRequest(method, URLString, headers: headers)
    let encodedURLRequest = encoding.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
    return request(encodedURLRequest)
}
```

Comment: Can you post the actual code of the `request` method? Have you activated the breakpoints for exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters` returns an optional, and when you do string interpolation, you're going to get `Optional(...)` appearing in the string. Thus when it tries to create a URL from that, it's undoubtedly failing. Print the `uri` string and you'll see the issue. E.g., if the `searchTerm` was `"foo bar"`, the `uri` would become:

```
https://api.spotify.com/v1/search&q=Optional("foo%20bar")&type=artist,album,track
```

But that's not correct. Add a `!` to the end of the expression to unwrap it:

```
let searchTermEncoded = searchTerm.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!
```

And then the URI will be (largely) correct.

--

I'd suggest not doing this percent escaping yourself (as the character set you're using is not correct, even once you do properly unwrap `searchTermEncoded`). Let Alamofire do this for you:

```
let urlString = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search"
let parameters = ["q" : searchTerm, "type" : "artist,album,track"]

Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString, parameters: parameters)
    .responseJSON { response  in
        guard response.result.error == nil else {
            print(response.result.error)
            return
        }

        print(response.result.value)
}
```

Comment: That's not it. I printed and it worked just fine. Even when I hard code the URL as the second parameter, it still bombs out. Also, remember, this works exactly as expected in the simulator and only errors when running on my device. Here's a screenshot of it. http://imgur.com/TwH4rya

Comment: Ok, let me give your second edit a try. I like that approach better anyway.

Comment: Nope, not that either, but once I fix the issue, I'll use that approach. Thanks for that! Here's a screenshot with the new code but the same error. http://imgur.com/Hmjcup2

Comment: I have. Multiple times. Also, I've changed my code so that I'm no longer encoding the search term myself and allowing the library to do the encoding for me.

Comment: @dstepan - If that's true, would appear that the crashing is unrelated to these errors in the code snippet. Try creating a new test project with the corrected code snippet and see if it works. Then go back and start reproducing stuff from your existing project into the new project until you can reproduce the problem. But I'm using the code snippet from my answer without incident, so it's likely something about your project or how Alamofire was added to the project.

Comment: @dstepan - BTW, I'm also using Xcode 7.1 (7B91b) and Alamofire 3.1.2.

Comment: but why would this work locally but not on my device if that were the case?

Comment: @dstepan - I'm not sure. I'm testing it on 9.1 device (with above config) and it works fine. That's why I'm suggesting creating a new project and seeing if it's something unique to that existing project. We need to make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem, and until we (or you) can reproduce the behavior you describe in a new project, it's hard to diagnose.

Comment: Understood. I'm going to try a few things and I'll report back.

Comment: Rob - I created a new project and moved all my files to the new project and after rebuilding everything, I got everything to work. Still not sure what the error was, but at this point I don't care. Thank you for taking the time to help.

Comment: As an aside, I sometimes see unexplainable errors when opening old projects in a new version of Xcode. Sometimes choosing "Validate settings..." from the "Editor" menu while the target settings are shown will fix it. But I'm glad you got around the problem one way or the other!